# jquery set class based on other element height

Tags: jquery, height, element

i'm new to jquery

Here is what i want to achive, with jquery: if the div id 1 has a bigger height than the window height, set a class only to div id 1

```
<div id="1">some text</div>
<div id="2">some text</div>
<div id="3">some text</div>
```

Thank you

Comment: what does the `set class to iteself?` thing mean?
Please provide names of the classes... That will be easier for us to answer your question :)

Comment: sorry, i updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a sample:

```
$(function() {
    $(window).resize(function() { //whenever window is resized
        var el = $('#1');         //caches the selector
        if (el.height() > $(window).height())   //if #1.height > window.height
            el.addClass('LargerThanWindow');    //add a class to it
        else
            el.removeClass('LargerThanWindow'); //else remove the class
    }).resize(); //triggers the resize handler which we just set inside the 
});              //DOM ready event
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/J2PAw/6/)
Resize the window vertically and you will see the class applied/removed.